# Why did they devise c++ glvalue covering both lvalue and xvalue?

Tags: c++

I am reading [Value categories](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category).

It says evaluation of a glvalue determines the identity of an object, ...

Usually an xvalue has no name, as "X(1)" in the following example.

```
struct X {
  int a;
  X(int a_) : a(a_) {}
};
printf("%d\n", X(1).a);
```

How does an anonymous one determine the identity of something?

The reference says the following three properties of glvalue.

> - A glvalue may be implicitly converted to a prvalue with lvalue-to-rvalue, > array-to-pointer, or function-to-pointer implicit conversion.
> - A glvalue may be polymorphic: the dynamic type of the object it identifies is > not necessarily the static type of the expression.
> - A glvalue can have incomplete type, where permitted by the expression.

I don't see any idea related to the identity.

So my question is, what features does an xvalue have in common compared to an lvalue, enough to be called a generalized lvalue?

Comment: You can get an explanation of the "new" value treminology straight from Bjarne Stroustrup himself: https://www.stroustrup.com/terminology.pdf

Comment: You can think of determining the identity as producing the object itself. It's not the same as identifying a person, where you need to determine some agreement between that person and some external identifying signifier such as a name or a social security number or something like that. In this context, you determine your own "identity" just by being (because you are you and not somebody else).